# What to know about turning ps3 into ubuntu desktop

Tags: 13.04, ps3

I have ps3 slim that i dont use so much any more and i was thinking i would like a desktop maybe i can recycle and use this :D has anyone have experience running ubuntu on ps3 as a full time desktop? can I still run apps to do some light web developing?

If someone can point me to some benchmark performance that would be very nice of you!

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Playstation 3 was once able to boot into alternative OS' until Sony changed their firmware for the worse, so now you need to follow certain instructions to be able to boot from Ubuntu and other operating systems, hope this link helps: http://www.pshomebrew.net/wiki/Installing_Ubuntu_on_PS3